# How do I perform the following join in SQL?

Tags: sql

Suppose I have the following table GAME

```
match_id, user_id, score
1, 10, 45
1, 11, 57
2, 10, 39
2, 14, 63
```

Now I want to do a query which gets player 10 and presents his score along with the score of his opponents like this

```
match_id, user_id, score, opponent_id, opponent_score
1, 10, 45, 11, 57
2, 10, 39, 14, 63
```

Comment: have you considered changing your table so it's (match_id, player1_id, player1_score, player2_id, player2_score)? Your question seems to make the assumption that there are always 2 players. If you cannot make that assumption, then what do you want to return in the case there are more than 2 players in a match?

Comment: What database system and what version are you using??

Comment: This looks an awful lot like my homework assignment due on Friday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select  P.match_id,
        P.user_id,
        P.score,
        O.user_id as opponent_id,
        O.score as opponent_score
  from  GAME P
  join  GAME O
    on  O.match_id = P.match_id
    and O.user_id <> P.user_id
  where P.user_id = 10
order by P.match_id
```

using table aliases P for 'player', O for 'opponent'

Marc points out this can vary by databases. The alternative join syntax - on the off-chance you're using e.g. an old Informix - would be to list both tables on the from and move the join-on clauses into the where, e.g.

```
  from  GAME P, GAME O
  where O.match_id = P.match_id
    and O.user_id <> P.user_id
    and P.user_id = 10
```

but the `join` should work for most.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    a.match_id,
    a.user_id AS user_id,
    a.score AS score,
    b.user_id AS opponent_id,
    b.score AS opponent_score
FROM
    game a
JOIN
    game b
ON
    a.match_id = b.match_id
AND
    a.user_id <> b.user_id
WHERE
    a.user_id = 10
```

Edit: Made the query work like it should. But look at Rup's answer to see it better done.

Comment: did you actually try to run this?

Comment: mmh, after I see the answer from Rup I'm not sure anymore. That "O.user_id <> P.user_id" is necessary as well. So, no, I didn't run it, sorry, and Rup gave a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    U.match_id,
    U.user_id,
    U.score,
    O.user_id as opponent_id,
    O.score as opponent_score
from GAME U
    inner join GAME O on 
        U.match_id = O.match_id and
        U.user_id <> O.user_id
where U.user_id = 10
```